# Saving uibutton state in custom cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I have a `custom cell` with two `uibuttons`.
Click on one of the buttons appends rows also based on a custom cell with two `uibuttons`.

Once the button is clicked i'm changing it's `alpha` to 50% and the boolean `isPressed` is set to true. So the next time user presses the button it would produce an `alert view` with error.

The issue is - each time i scroll - the cells with the buttons **are being reused** and those two rules are applied chaotically.

I've browsed answers on stack, but haven't seen anything that would help me, especially in swift. I'm aware that it is possible to create an array, append it with `boolean`, `indexPath.row` or `currentTitle` objects - then somehow use this array while scrolling the tableview. But the implementation isn't clear to me. Whats more difficult is that i have two buttons in one row.

Would appreciate any help on that subject.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea implemented in objc will look like this:

1. Create an NSArray with size equals numbers of cells.
2. Initialise it with objects like `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:NO]` (or
   `YES` if you need pressed state) before you call `[self.tableView reloadData];`
3. In method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if
   `[array[indexPath.row] boolValue]` is YES or NO and set button's
   state.

Hopes it will help.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of tutorials on table views. [Like here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/). You need to separate the model of your data (like whether buttons have been pressed or not) from the view (the cells and buttons in the table). If this idea isn't clear, you'll want to look up MVC (model view controller) or MVVM (model view view-model).

The idea is that you have a record, for example in an array, of what all of the items in your table should look like, regardless of whether or not they're on the screen. When you need to show a cell, you overwrite its current state (since it is being recycled) with what it should be - based on the information in the array.

Comment: i've implemented the tableview and it works quite fine. the only issue remains - is saving the clicked state of a range of buttons and overwriting it to what it should be. Can you please explain further, what do you mean by "what all of the items should look like" - what exact information do i put in array? how do i check the state of the button according to the array then?

Comment: You need an object that is modeling your data. For example, a simple `struct` with two booleans, each representing whether or not one of your buttons was pressed. Then you'll have an array of these `struct`s. The table will be populated based on the number of items in the array, and in the data source's `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, you should update the cell based on the information in the struct that is in the array at index `indexPath.row`.